# Typescript - Enum exported in other file throws 'enum is not defined' even after import

Tags: typescript, enums

I have the following ts file where I have an enum defined:

**enumFile.ts**

```
export enum myEnum {
    "One" = 'test_1',
    "Two" = 'test_2',
    "Three" = 'test_3'
}
```

I am using this enum in the following ts file like this.

**test.ts**

```
import {myEnum} from '../demo/enumFile'

export default class Runner {
    StartRun(testCaseData) {
       console.log(myEnum.One)                       // This works
       const MyEnumInstance = eval("myEnum")    // This doesn't work
   }
}
```

I get an error saying **'Reference Error: myEnum is not defined'** when I try to access the enum via 'eval'. I'm using 'eval' as I want to extract data from the enum dynamically.
If I define the enum in the test.ts file, then the 'eval' also works fine but it doesn't work if my enum is in another file.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Is you enum class in the right directory? Did you save the files you're working with?

Comment: Yes, the files are saved and verified the path also. I am seeing this error for enums that exist in a separate file.

Comment: Can you make a little sandbox that reproduces the problem?